# Failed to compute auto layout status IBLayoutConstraint and IBUICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, size-classes

I am working with a project with 2 different layout configurations for phones and tables. After a few changes in the phones layout, every time I try to change the size class from wAnyxhAny to wRegularxhRegular, XCode crashes and I get that error. I can't work 
Any idea???

Comment: You will need to log a bug with Apple at: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, if you add constraints to a hidden size class that conflict with each other, XCode won't be able to render the storyboard view and crash. I had to manually disable every constraint until XCode stopped crashing.
This is a serious bug.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had copied the view from another size class wR wR to wA wA.

This left me with a load of uninstalled wR wR constraints, it wasn't till I deleted these by hitting the little x that xcode started working properly again.

[image: constraint example]